# Adding multiple arrays at once perl

Tags: arrays, perl, sum

I have about 50 arrays filled with numbers and I have to report out a sum of all those elements for every array so the end result has 50 sums of individual arrays.

Is there any shorter way to do it rather than writing different for loop for every array?

I am a beginner with perl. Any helpful comments/suggestions would be appreciated.

This is my code so far:

```
for( $j = 1 ; $j <= 50 ; $j++ ) {
  for ( @arr[$j] ) {
    $sum[$j] += $_;
  }
  print $sum[$j];
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: How are the 50 arrays structured? Do you have an "array of arrays", or do you have 50 individual arrays?

Comment: Your looping appears to be off by one, er, by two, starting at the second element of `@arr` (index `$j` is 1) and ending at the fifty-first element (index 50).  Perl's more expressive loops — `for my $whatever (@whatevers)` — avoid this kind of error, as does `while (my ($index, $element) = each(@array))` available in 5.12 and later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Util) and [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html), assuming you have an array of arrays:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper; 
use List::Util qw(sum);

my @arrays = (
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]
); 
my @sums   = map sum(@$_), @arrays;   # sum each array
print Dumper \@sums;
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          '6',       # sum of $arrays[0]
          '15',      #                1
          '24'       #                2
        ];
```

Comment: Hey I really appreciate your answer and it works perfectly fine but my output has to be displayed in a proper way. Is there anyway I can get rid of "$VAR1" in my output and put some other text before sums of every array? what I need to do is:
Sum of array 1: 6
Sum of array 2: 15
Sum of array 3: 24 and so on
I would really appreciate your feedback on this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user1297069 Well, I assumed you would know with your own data, but one way to do that particular print is `print "Sum of array $_: $sums[$_]\n" for keys @sums`

Comment: alright cool thanks again for all your help! Def made my job much easier

Answer (score 4):

```
use strict; use warnings;

use List::Util qw ( sum );

my %data = (
   cats => [ map +(rand 100), 1 .. 10 ],
   dogs => [ map +(100 - rand 100), 1 .. 20 ],
);

my %sums = map { $_ => sum(@{ $data{$_} }) } keys %data;

use YAML;
print Dump \%data, \%sums;
```

Answer (score 2):

For TIMTOWTDI!

```
# You cannot store arrays within arrays just with ((...), (...)) syntax, 
# as this list will be flattened.
# Instead you should store _references_ to arrays, like this:
my @array_of_arrays = ([1..3], [4..6], [8..10]); 
my @sums_of_arrays;

# ... then iterate over it, arrayref by arrayref
# (if `map` is somehow not for you) :)
for my $ref_arr (@array_of_arrays) {
   my $arr_sum;
   for my $el (@$ref_arr) {
     $arr_sum += $el;
   }
   push @sums_of_arrays, $arr_sum;
}
```

Take note, though, that I consider this solution inferior to those given by @TLP and @SinanÜnür. ) `For` construct is good when you need to do something (transform, for example) with each element of array (or array of arrays, as in this case). But here you just need something for each element - in other words, a map. )